# LARAVEL:send mail from gmail account?

Tags: laravel, smtp, gmail

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "bisd.ensa@gamil.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials k12sm6011555wrd.75 - gsmtp ". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials k12sm6011555wrd.75 - gsmtp ". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials k12sm6011555wrd.75 - gsmtp ".
> any solution please??

Comment: typo in the email address? `bisd.ensa@gamil.com` -> `bisd.ensa@gmail.com`

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that you are trying to login to the Gmail smtp server using the users login and password.

As the message states you should set up [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol) Using Xoauth2 will allow you to authorze the user using Oauth2 and then you can send an access token with your request rather than the user password

> user=someuser@example.com^Aauth=Bearer ya29.vF9dft4qmTc2Nvb3RlckBhdHRhdmlzdGEuY29tCg^A^A

Alternatively you could try setting up an [apps password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) for the account this often works as well. Even though your error message does not mention it.